# Авто-повышение user_role на сайте WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Хочу сделать на сайте такую функцию, к примеру - если пользователь делает 100 публикаций ему автоматически назначается статус Редактора, 200 - Администратор и т.п.

Comment: И придет спам-бот, кинет 200 постов, станет админом и грохнет ваш сайт. Просто так, из вредности.

Comment: Это я привел простой пример, на самом деле после удачной оплаты будет назначен статус пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В гугле и на Stack уже есть подобные посты.

```
<?php 

 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 $user = $current_user->ID;

 if(count_user_posts( $user /*user id*/)>= 200){ 
    // Remove role
    $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' ); 
    // Add role
    $user->add_role( 'editor' );
 } 

?>
```

---

- Функция: [Count_user_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts)
- Функция: [Remove_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_role)
- Функция: [Aadd_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role)
- Функция: [wp_get_current_user](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_current_user)